# Avoid use of the visitor pattern in this very common scenario

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, polymorphism, visitor-pattern

Let's assume we need to send a message, and to do so we would like our client to be concerned only with constructing the message (DTO) and using a facade service to send it.

We already know that we could have various services capable of sending messages of different types and we want to avoid going to change our structure every time a new message type or a new sending service is implemented.

The first way to approach the problem is to identify it as a "double dispatch" problem and then fix it with the visitor pattern.

```
internal interface IMessage
{
    string Content { get; }

    void UseDispatcher(IMessageDispatcher dispatcher);
}

internal class NotificationMessage : IMessage
{
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public void UseDispatcher(IMessageDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        dispatcher.SendNotification(this);
    }
}

internal class MailMessage : IMessage
{
    public string Object { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public MailAddress Recipient { get; set; }

    public void UseDispatcher(IMessageDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        dispatcher.SendEmail(this);
    }
}

internal interface IMessageDispatcher
{
    void SendNotification(NotificationMessage message);

    void SendEmail(MailMessage email);
}

internal interface IMessageSender<TMessage>
    where TMessage : IMessage
{
    void Send(TMessage message);
}

internal class MailSender : IMessageSender<MailMessage>
{
    public void Send(MailMessage message)
    {
    }
}

internal class NotificationSender : IMessageSender<NotificationMessage>
{
    public void Send(NotificationMessage message)
    {
    }
}

internal class MessageDispatcher : IMessageDispatcher
{
    private readonly MailSender mailSender;
    private readonly NotificationSender notificationSender;

    public void SendEmail(MailMessage email)
    {
        mailSender.Send(email);
    }

    public void SendNotification(NotificationMessage message)
    {
        notificationSender.Send(message);
    }
}

internal class MessagesManager
{
    private IMessageDispatcher dispatcher;

    public void Send(IMessage message)
    {
        message.UseDispatcher(dispatcher);
    }
}
```

The problem with this architecture is that when we implement a new sender service we are also forced to modify the MessageDispatcher.

Could this be considered a violation of the open/close principle?
I think the MessageDispatcher service is not "closed" to changes in this case.
I also dislike the fact that an IMessage contains logic and is no longer a simple DTO and we should add more complexity to avoid that.

I usually avoid using this approach for these reasons and prefer modes that maybe use reflection.

Are there other methods that solve the problem in a more elegant way?

Comment: Why do consumers of the message dispatcher need to know if you are sending an e-mail versus a notification? Why now just use `dispatcher.Send(message)`?

Comment: Can you explain a little about why you need this level of complication?  Are you expecting to create many more IMessage types?  Most of the time that I've seen this kind of thing (or built it) I have found that there was little to no need for it.  Can you give more information around the context where this would be called?

Comment: This code looks like it's reinventing the `MediatR` library - https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR (It looks to me that MediatR has already solved the problem described here - i.e. MediatR doesn't require you to change the library in order to add new message types or new handlers)

Comment: @GregBurghardt: it is not possible to keep a generic IMessage otherwise we would have to check the specific type in order to use it.

Comment: @BenCottrell MediatR is the solution with reflection.

Comment: @blow MediatR stores an internal Dictionary mapping a `Type` to a handler, so it uses plain old casting without needing reflection; however my point is that there are existing libraries out there which solve the problem described in the question without needing to reinvent the wheel.  (someone else has already done all the hard work of implementing the pattern for you, as well as having had it tested out in the wild and thoroughly peer reviewed)

Comment: No, it's just a different kind of `if(instance is ....)` and it's clear in my question that this kind of solution it is well known and often preferred to the architecture with the vistor pattern that I have described. Also please, whoever downvotes it must argue why, my question is legitimate and well asked.

Comment: And MediatR use a lot of reflection. Check namespaces.

Comment: You didn't answer my previous question, but I thought I'd throw this out: whatever is deserializing the object from the wire format must, at some level determine what type it needs to create.  The problem of finding the right handler is therefore somewhat artificial.  If you don't lose track of that determination, you don't really need any fancy pattern here.  There's nothing wrong with using reflection to 'recover' that information, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem with this architecture is that when we implement a new sender service we are also forced to modify the MessageDispatcher.

This is arguably a good thing, since the compiler will force you to add a sender whenever creating a new message.

> Could this be considered a violation of the open/close principle?

Yes, but I would recommend a pragmatic approach to the open closed principle. While modification is necessary, the class is very simple and easy to update. And the compiler will force you do do an update, so there is no risk of forgetting.

> I also dislike the fact that an IMessage contains logic and is no longer a simple DTO and we should add more complexity to avoid that.

I would not worry to much about trivial logic like this. I would again suggest a more pragmatic than dogmatic view. If you add more complexity just to follow the dogma you risk ending up with a solution that is more complex overall.

> Are there other methods that solve the problem in a more elegant way?

Reflection is almost certainly an alternative. You could create an attribute for your messages, something like `[MessageSender(typeof(NotificationSender))]`, and use reflection to create the sender object at runtime.

Or you could use a dependency injection approach, something like

```
var senderType = typeof(IMessageSender<>).MakeGenericType(new []{myMessageObject.GetType()});
myDiContainer.Resolve(senderType);
```

Or just a switch over the message type to map it to the corresponding sender.

But in all of these solutions you will be turning compile time errors into runtime errors. And you will have the risk of forgetting to add the corresponding sender whenever adding a new message type. This might not be a large problem if you have appropriate testing etc, but it is a tradeoff you need to consider.